# How can I resolve the 'Permission Denied' error when pushing tags to Git from Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: git, github, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I am are creating a CI/CD pipeline with Jenkins and ran into a problem when I try and run the following line.

`bat "git push origin --tags"`

I have above this line created the new tags that need generated when doing deployments.

But the problem is I get the following error when I run the pipeline.

[Pipeline Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaOW9.png)

When I run the git command from the command window when pointed to the same workspace the tags are pushed successfully.

Hopping that someone can help.

I have looked at other Stack overflows that talk about how to fix the problem and in each instance I get other error messages.

Comment: The error is quite explicit. You do not have permission *as the Jenkins user* to perform this operation. Bear in mind your git command is running using whatever account is being used to run the Jenkins instance. If you add a `bat script: "whoami"` you can get it to tell you. `bat script: "set"` is also useful for dumping the environment which has lots of useful information. Github may be requiring a 2FA key as well.

Comment: So even though Jenkins was set up to use a specific user account that can execute the git push from a command prompt doesnt mean it runs the commands as that user. As I am trying to use user A but the "whoami" says we are running as system.